# JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error

Tags: json, ajax

DataTables warning (table id = 'city'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

my json data looks like this, I am trying to set the json data to data tables

```
 {"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[{"id":"1","vid":"A0001","date":"2019-02-07 15:58:53","latitude":"17.00","longitude":"82.20","speed":"25","batery":"98","totalkm":"8","intrkm":"8","control":"0"},{"id":"2","vid":"A0001","date":"2019-02-07 15:58:53","latitude":"17.10","longitude":"82.30","speed":"26","batery":"97","totalkm":"15","intrkm":"15","control":"0"}]}
```

i write a script code like this achieve that

```
 <script>
  function getId(val) {
    $.ajax({
     type: "post",
    url: "getdata.php",
    data: 'id=' + val,
    dataType: "text",                  
    success: function(response){                    
        $('#city').dataTable({
             "bProcessing": true,
             "sAjaxSource": "getdata.php",
             "aoColumns": [
                    { mData: 'id' } ,
                    { mData: 'vid' },
                    { mData: 'date' },
                    { mData: 'latitude' },
                    { mData: 'longitude' },
                    { mData: 'speed' },
                    { mData: 'batery' },
                    { mData: 'totalkm' },
                    { mData: 'intrkm' },
                    { mData: 'control' }

            ]
       }); 
       }

 });

   }
</script>
```

while doing this the datatable shows processing.... but not correctly loading datatables. I don't know whats wrong in it. Help me if any code has to change

Comment: dataType: "text" change to dataType:"JSON"

Comment: i have changed that but i am unable to load tha datatable